# Как получить путь к текущему скрипту в Perl6?

Tags: perl

Я хочу получить путь к текущему скрипту.
Я знаю, что есть `$*CWD`, но эта конструкция возвращает результат в странном формате:

> "c:\Download\1897300ed3\336543".IO

а мне нужно:

> c:\Download\1897300ed3\336543

Как получить путь в таком виде?

Comment: вы ветко ошиблис, с такйо формулировкой вам на SO нужно а не на SO на русском.

Comment: А зачем вам путь в таком виде? Какова конечная задача? Вам возвращается объект `IO::Path`.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался..
Путь можно показать так:

> say $*CWD.path;